# Kentico: Issue related to the XML data Source, 403 error

Tags: kentico

I am getting the **(403) Forbidden** error in the Event Log of a Kentico website. The screenshot of the event log are shown below:

[image]

[image]

I have checked the Data Source web part used on the **/home** page and the URL from where i am getting XML data is also correct. So I am unable to understand what can be the cause of this type of error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the XML Data source point to?  A local file or a url?  403 is usually due to file security issues, are your files set to be readable by the Application pool?

Comment: Are you able to use Postman to call the same URL with the same settings? (https://www.getpostman.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Is someone blocking Baiduspider from making requests to the XML file? There is a webRequest for XML url in place, for which default .net credentials from CredentialCache and user agent from current request is used. If the server or page with XML is blocking robots for example, this exception can occur.